# How to find if any values in pandas data frame are duplicated and rerun a piece of code after user confirmation

Tags: python, pandas

I am pulling a google sheet into a dataframe and I'm trying to first find if any of the values in a specific column are duplicates and then ask the user to fix the issue on the google sheet and rerun that part of the code again. Where I'm stuck is - how to trigger to rerun the code if any values are true. This is what I have so far - my approach was to check with duplicated() and add a column to the dataframe. The reason I wanted to do that is so I can filter and then show the user which rows have issues specifically.

```
id | record_id | 
0  | abc1      |
1  | abc2      |
2  | abc3      |
3  | abc1      |
```

This is the code I tried so far:

```
df ['record_id_duplicate']  = df.duplicated(subset='record_id',keep=False)

record_id_validation = None
if 'True' in df ['record_id_duplicate']:
    record_id_validation = True
else:
    False
```

I do get the column added correctly - but not really sure where to go from here.
This is how df looks after I added duplicated column. Any help would be appreciated

```
id | record_id | record_id_duplicate
0  | abc1      |True
1  | abc2      |False
2  | abc3      |False
3  | abc1      |True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `any` on boolean type column which will return `True` if any of the values in the column is `True`, else it returns `False` if none of the value is `True`:

```py
>>> df['record_id_duplicate'].any()
True
```

Comment: Yea that’s what I have already. I’m trying to understand if there a way to create another variable that will be either true or false if any values in that column  are true

Comment: Apologies, I initially did not get the question, I've updated the answer